# Why my hierarchy query is showing duplicate records?

Tags: sql, oracle

My requirement is to find all lapsed days in a month. Below are my sample queries.

```
CREATE TABLE custom.date_full (
    sno         NUMBER,
    curr_date   DATE);

INSERT INTO custom.date_full VALUES ( 1,'27-sep-2018' );
INSERT INTO custom.date_full VALUES ( 2,'27-sep-2018' );

--Query:1 - RETURNS 4 RECORDS AS EXPECTED
 SELECT  curr_date, 
        TRUNC (curr_date, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1 AS DAY,
        LEVEL 
   FROM (SELECT * FROM custom.date_full WHERE sno=1)
CONNECT BY level<=4
  ORDER BY DAY;

--Query 2: RETURNS 15 RECORDS WITH DUPLICATES
SELECT  curr_date, 
        TRUNC (curr_date, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1 AS DAY,
        LEVEL 
   FROM custom.date_full 
  WHERE sno=1
CONNECT BY level<=4
  ORDER BY DAY;
```

My `Query 1` works good but `Query 2` is showing duplicate records. Why?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you're also missing a condition from your connect by statement in the second query (assuming that `sno` is a unique column): `and prior sno = sno`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not understanding how `CONNECT BY` works.  Here is a walkthrough of how Oracle is evaluating your 2nd query.

Without a `START WITH` clause, every row in your table with be used as a starting point, or "root" in your hierarchy.

Since you have no `CONNECT BY` conditions (like "columnA = PRIOR columnB"), every row in your table will be considered a child of every other row.  This will happen forever, until your `LEVEL <=4` condition is reached.

So,

```
LEVEL 1
--------
SNO 1
SNO 2
```

Explanation: Each row in your table is a starting point of its own hierarchy (because you have no `START WITH` conditions).

```
LEVEL 2
--------
SNO 1 -> SNO 1
SNO 1 -> SNO 2 
SNO 2 -> SNO 1
SNO 2 -> SNO 2
```

Explanation of those 4 rows -- both SNO 1 and SNO 2 are roots, and for each root, SNO 1 and SNO 2 are children.  So, 2x2 rows = 4 rows.

```
LEVEL 3 
-------
SNO 1 -> SNO 1 -> SNO 1
SNO 1 -> SNO 1 -> SNO 2
SNO 1 -> SNO 2 -> SNO 1 
SNO 1 -> SNO 2 -> SNO 2 
SNO 2 -> SNO 1 -> SNO 1
SNO 2 -> SNO 1 -> SNO 2
SNO 2 -> SNO 2 -> SNO 1
SNO 2 -> SNO 2 -> SNO 2
```

Explanation of those 8 rows.  Starting with the 4 rows from level 2, both SNO 1 and SNO 2 are children of each, giving 4x2 = 8 rows at level 3.

Level 4, which I won't draw out, will similarly give 8x2 = 16 rows.

So, in total, you have 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 30 rows.  (That's level 1 + level 2 + level 3 + level 4).

Then, *after* your `CONNECT BY` processing (shown above), the `WHERE` clause is applied, limiting your final results to rows where the value (at the lowest level of the hierarchy) is `SNO = 1`.  That is exactly half of the 30 rows, or 15 rows, which is what you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Using `CONNECT BY` creates a hierarchical query. Typically, this also includes a `START WITH` that specifies rows that are the parent/root of the hierarchical query. When there is no `START WITH`, all rows in the table are used as parent/root rows.

In `Query 1`, the parent/root is a table with 1 row:

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM custom.date_full WHERE sno=1)
```

In `Query 2`, the parent/root is a table with 2 rows:

```
FROM custom.date_full
```

This `START WITH` and `CONNECT BY` relationship determines how rows in the hierarchy will be connected in the results.

There are no duplicates in `Query` because there is only a single parent row with relationships to multiple child rows.

There are duplicate results in `Query 2` because there are multiple parent rows with relationships to multiple child rows.

---

More general information is available in the following resources:

- [Oracle documentation on Hierarchical Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)
- [How the start with CONNECT BY clause in Oracle works](http://www.oradev.com/connect_by.jsp).

Comment: But i have restricted the data using `WHERE sno=1`.

Comment: As noted in [Matthew McPeak's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52950841/2657515), `WHERE` is applied *after* `CONNECT BY`