# Remove duplicate in CONNECT BY LEVEL query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've tried find all days between 2 dates and I have a query here

```
with tmp as(
  select 1 sno, to_date('20181227', 'YYYYMMDD') curr_date, to_date('20181231', 'YYYYMMDD') curr_date2 from dual
  union all
  select 2 sno, to_date('20181227', 'YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20181231', 'YYYYMMDD') from dual
)
 SELECT sno, curr_date + level - 1 DAY, LEVEL 
   FROM tmp
CONNECT BY curr_date + level -1 <= curr_date2
```

But I received duplicate result and I found because of missing `START WITH` clause [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950407/why-my-hierarchy-query-is-showing-duplicate-records) but I don't know `START WITH` where!!

I still can't find any solution to remove duplicate at result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`prior + sys_guid`](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=sys-guid-in-connect-by-level) method.

```
...
CONNECT BY curr_date + level -1 <= curr_date2
and prior sno = sno
and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f935ab2721cea6cd0c0cd5c0de6e0b03)

Comment: It really helpful, thank you so much!! But what is sys_guid() function mechanism in this query??

Comment: @hungtt : `SYS_GUID` generates and returns a globally unique identifier. It is to avoid cycles in the connect by loop. Read more on this  link :https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526535

Comment: I accepted it, but because of new contributor I can't vote for you although I do it many times. Thanks for very useful answer!